# Should I use boost::variant?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

My virtual function can return either a single `T` or `std::vector<T>`. Is it a good idea to return `boost::variant<T, std::vector<T>>` in this case or it's better to always return `std::vector<T>`? Which looks better and has the least performance overhead? Is it faster to use variant when a single value is returned?

Comment: Forget about performance until your profiler tells you that you have a bottleneck. As for the dilemma whether to use a `vector<T>` or a `variant<T, vector<T>>`, I think it is impossible to give an answer without knowing the semantics of your function.

Comment: Keep it simple, return `std::vector`, in both cases you will have to check if you have one element `T` (`size() == 1`) or many.

Comment: I don't think so, static visitor doesn't have to perform this check.

Comment: @lizarisk, I mean, in terms of coding at least (something must be done at runtime anyway, right?). If you don't have all the infreastructure for doing "something" with the `variant` already in place, then it will be a pain. (I am not saying that the variant solution is not more elegant in the long term, just giving a practical recommendation)

Comment: @lizarisk how do you think the visitor works at runtime?  An equivalent check.

Comment: I may have not made it clear, but the type returned (either `T` or `std::vector<T>`) depends on the implementation of a virtual function, not on some condition inside the function itself. So it's somehow a part of the interface, that's why I've thought of `boost::variant` as a solution.

Comment: `boost::static_visitor` works at compile time, so no overhead and virtual functions here.

Comment: @AndyProwl, I often face this dilemma for example when finding all the roots of a function. It can have one or many (or none) and certainly the case with one root is "prototypical" in the sense that a set of subsequent operations are done in the single (or multiple roots) (think of it as branching), in the prototypical case `std::vector` seems a waste because everything has to be "iterated" later. So that can be a semantic example (unless lizarisk give another one). (lizarisk, please post an example.)

Comment: I mentioned virtual functions because I have a very broad interface with a lot of implementations. Most of them always return single value and I thought this can be a special case which is reflected in the interface.

Comment: I don't think so, if the correct function to call (execution path) is dispatched at compile time there should be no additional overhead. What else do you mean by "visitation"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance concerns aside, this depends on the semantics of your function, or more precisely of the return value.

Do you often need to distinguish (code path wise) between the case where only one `T` is returned and the multi value case? Or can a simple `for(auto t : create_T_orTs()) { ... }` do the right thing in either case?

My gut feeling is that the former is less likely than the latter, and since `variant<>` comes with a syntactic 'price' I'd go with KISS and use a `std::vector<T>`, unless there is a strong **semantic** reason to distinguish the one and the multiple value cases.